# Split fullname in Mysql and update columns firstname and lastname

Tags: mysql

I got a table with the column 'fullname' and columns firstname and lastname which are null.

| fullname | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doe, John | null | null |
| Dow, Jones | null | null |

I want to create an update query, which splits the fullname and updates the columns firstname and lastname.

I tried:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1,

(SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ",", -1)) AS t2firstname FROM tablename) AS t2,

(SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ",", 1)) AS t3lastname FROM tablename) AS t3

SET t1.firstname = t2.t2firstname,
    t1.lastname = t3.t3lastname
```

However, this updates firstname and lastname in all rows from the very first row:

| fullname | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doe, John | John | Doe |
| Dow, Jones | John | Doe |

How can I do this separately for each row?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `UPDATE` statement do the job?  ie `UPDATE tablename SET firstname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',' -1), lastname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ',', 1);`

Comment: You might also want to wrap those expressions in `TRIM(` ... `)` in order to remove any spaces before/after firstname or lastname